# Lambda function "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT" when receive too many requests for MySQL query

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda, load-testing, serverless

I am trying to do testing on my AWS lambda function which makes a query to RDS MySQL (t2.medium).
However, if I request the API a large number of times, although I can get query successfully with correct data, it sometimes results "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT".

Is there anything  wrong in my code or setting?

I read some suggestions to set some parameters:

MySQL:

> wait_timeout  1
>
> max_connections   16000
>
> interactive_timeout   6000
>
> max_allowed_packet    1073741824

Lamdba:

> Timeout 60 sec place the Lambda function in the same VPC as your RDS
>
> Added VPC execution policy AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
>
> assign a security group to the lambda function
>
> In the security attached to the RDS instance, added an inbound rule
>   for mysql
>
> Confirm that Lambda function has access to the same VPC RDS database

Lambda Error Log

> 2019-03-28T18:51:47.353Z  ab4fbbaf-1ea2-458b-a5b5-781cdfdd80df    { Error:
>   connect ETIMEDOUT
>
> at Connection._handleConnectTimeout
>
> (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:411:13)
>
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
>
> at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
>
> at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
>
> at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:420:8)
>
> at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
>
> at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
>
> at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
>
> ---
>
> at Protocol._enqueue
>   (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
>
> at Protocol.handshake
>   (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
>
> at Connection.connect
>   (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:118:18)
>
> at Connection._implyConnect
>   (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:453:10)
>
> at Connection.query 
>   (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:198:8)
>
> at Promise (/var/task/db.js:62:9)
>
> at new Promise ()
>
> at Object.retrieve (/var/task/db.js:55:10)
>
> at exports.getAlerts (/var/task/index.js:59:24)
>
> errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
>
> code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
>
> syscall: 'connect',
>
> fatal: true }

RDS Error Log

> 2019-03-28T18:18:49.378320Z 9500 [Note] Aborted connection 9500 to db:
>   'db' user: 'user' host: '123.123.123.123' (Got timeout reading
>   communication packets)
>
> 2019-03-28T18:18:49.392514Z 9498 [Note] Aborted connection 9498 to db:
>   'db' user: 'user' host: '123.123.123.123' (Got timeout reading
>   communication packets)
>
> 2019-03-28T18:18:49.470617Z 9499 [Note] Aborted connection 9499 to db:
>   'db' user: 'user' host: '123.123.123.123' (Got timeout reading
>   communication packets)
>
> 2019-03-28T18:18:49.636775Z 9501 [Note] Aborted connection 9501 to db:
>   'db' user: 'user' host: '123.123.123.123' (Got timeout reading
>   communication packets)
>
> 2019-03-28T18:18:49.694669Z 9502 [Note] Aborted connection 9502 to db:
>   'db' user: 'user' host: '123.123.123.123' (Got timeout reading
>   communication packets)
>
> 2019-03-28T18:18:49.803457Z 9503 [Note] Aborted connection 9503 to db:
>   'db' user: 'user' host: '123.123.123.123' (Got timeout reading
>   communication packets)
>
> 2019-03-28T18:18:49.824250Z 9504 [Note] Aborted connection 9504 to db:
>   'db' user: 'user' host: '123.123.123.123' (Got timeout reading
>   communication packets)

My db.js query  on lambda

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
let retrieve = (sql, objectArr, entityName) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let con = mysql.createConnection(dbParams)
        con.query(sql, objectArr, (err2, results) => {
          con.end()
          if (err2) {
            console.log(err2)
            return reject(new apiError.DatabaseError('An error occurred in retrieve'))
          }
          console.log('Data retrieve successfully')
          return resolve(results)
        })
      })
    }
```

My test.js script

```
const request = require('request')
let errorCount = 0
let success = 0

for (let i = 0; i < 4000; i++) {
  console.log('Send')
  request.get('https://myapi/users', {
    headers: {
      'client_id': 'app',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log('some error')
      errorCount++
    } else {
      let jsonBody = JSON.parse(body)
      if (jsonBody.code === 0) {
        success++
      } else {
        errorCount++
      }
    }

    console.log('Success: ', success)
    console.log('Error: ', errorCount)
  })
}
```

Edit:
I also tried to change the i < 1 in test script, then it always gives me "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT. But with i < 900, it works successfully sometime

index.js

```
const db = require('./db.js')
exports.getUsers = async (event, context) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false
  try {
    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM User'
    let abc = await db.retrieve(sql, [], 'user')

    let response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      abc: abc,
      code: 0
    }
    return response
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    errorHandler(err)
  }
}
```

db.js with Pool

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const constants = require('./constants.js')

let dbParams = {
  host: constants.SQL_CONNECTION_HOST,
  user: constants.SQL_CONNECTION_USER,
  password: constants.SQL_CONNECTION_PASSWORD,
  database: constants.SQL_CONNECTION_DATABASE,
  multipleStatements: true,
  maxConnections: 4
}

const pool = mysql.createPool(dbParams)
let retrieve = (sql, objectArr, entityName) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.getConnection((err1, con) => {
      if (err1) {
        console.log(err1)
        return reject(new apiError.DatabaseError('An error occurred in retrieve pool'))
      }
      console.log('Pool connect successfully')
      con.query(sql, objectArr, (err2, results) => {
        con.end()
        if (err2) {
          console.log(err2)
          return reject(new apiError.DatabaseError('An error occurred in retrieve'))
        }
        console.log('Data retrieve successfully')
        return resolve(results)
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Error Log after used pool

> 2019-03-28T23:35:24.144Z  91b0fc78-e4d1-4fd9-bdf7-923715b165c0    { Error:
>   Handshake inactivity timeout
>
> at Handshake.
>   (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:163:17)
>
> at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
>
> at Handshake.emit (events.js:208:7)
>
> at Handshake._onTimeout 
>   (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:124:8)
>
> at Timer._onTimeout 
>   (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Timer.js:32:23)
>
> at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
>
> at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
>
> at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
>
> ---
>
> at Protocol._enqueue 
>   (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
>
> at Protocol.handshake 
>   (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
>
> at PoolConnection.connect 
>   (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:118:18)
>
> at Pool.getConnection (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
>
> at Promise (/var/task/db.js:72:10)
>
> at new Promise ()
>
> at Object.retrieve (/var/task/db.js:67:10)
>
> at exports.getAlerts (/var/task/index.js:59:24)
>
> code: 'PROTOCOL_SEQUENCE_TIMEOUT',
>
> fatal: true,
>
> timeout: 10000 }

Set with Pool now and test it with request loop:

i < 100 result => Success: 866 and Error: 134 requests.

i < 10 result => Success: 8 and Error: 2 requests.

Error with Handshake inactivity timeout

db.js with con.createConnection outside

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
// initialize dbParams
let con = mysql.createConnection(dbParams)

let retrieve = (sql, objectArr, entityName) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    con.query(sql, objectArr, (err2, results) => {
      //con.end() commet out connection end here 
      if (err2) {
        console.log(err2)
        return reject(new apiError.DatabaseError('An error occurred in retrieve'))
      }
      console.log('Data retrieve successfully')
      return resolve(results)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: How many times is "a large number of times" and over how long of an interval did you do this? (example, 1000 times in 60 seconds)

Comment: `SELECT *` is mostly NEVER a good choice, especially without any limit... Maybe if you query less data it will take less time to retrieve it and timeout after more iterations. It is a nice test to stress all your system though

Comment: @Zyigh I currently have only 3 row data in the User table. I will set a limit after

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot I have set with Pool now and test it with i < 100 request loop. And resulting Success:  866 and Error:  134 requests. Error with 
Handshake inactivity timeout

Comment: So... 1000 attempts over what period of time?  Read up on MySQL's [`thread_cache_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_thread_cache_size) -- while probably not the entire issue, a MySQL server is not able to accept an indefinite number of connections in a short time, due to the overhead of OS thread creation.  The thread cache allows the server to keep them around for reuse.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks, everyone. I think there are two issues:
1. concurrency Unreserved account concurrency 1000
2. The lambda function should assign with only the VPC which RDS assigned to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not explained in the question how does the `retrieve` function is being called inside your lambda function.

Even though, it strongly seems that it will be executed for each iteration inside your test, which creates a very large number of connections and may explain the behavior you see.

I suggest creating the connection at lambda initialization time (aka 'coldstart'), by moving the code line `let con = mysql.createConnection(dbParams)` outside of any function (so that only a single connection will take place).

Another good option is to use [connection pooling](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections).

Comment: I tried with Pool, it also happens the same behavior with "Error: Handshake inactivity timeout". I have edited with index.js and db.js with Pool in post

Comment: So please try to initialize the connection once as suggested

Comment: I updated with let con = mysql.createConnection outside the function, but it also gives "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT". I provided the script on edit

Comment: Thanks. I found the issue, I assigned extra VPC subnet and availability zone which the server is not part of the subnet. Now, I changed my lambda function with only the database subnet and it works with no issue with 1000 connections